# SelectMany causes nested select in query

Tags: linq-to-entities

In my database I have four tables connected to each other: `backlog` -> `backlogsap` -> `partner` -> `contactprofile`

There is a one-to-many relationship between `partner` and `contactprofile`. Now, I have an ID for the backlog and I want to get all contact profiles connected to it so I'm doing the following:

```
dbContext.backlogs
    .Where(bl => bl.IdBacklog == idBacklog)
    .SelectMany(bl => bl.backlogsap.partner.contactprofiles)
```

*(Yes, in this particular case the ID is distinct so I could easily exchange the where with a single clause and then just get the contact profiles but for the sake of understanding, let's assume the where clause might return multiple rows.)*

This results in a query looking like this:

```
SELECT Join1.IdContactProfile, 
       Join1.Name, 
       Join1.EmailAddress, 
       Join1.LandlinePhone, 
       Join1.MobilePhone, 
       Join1.UseMail, 
       Join1.UseMobile, 
       Join1.IDPARTNER1 AS IdPartner
FROM backlog AS Extent1
INNER JOIN (SELECT Extent2.IdBacklogSap, 
                   Extent2.IdPartner, 
                   Extent2.IsDeleted, 
                   Extent2.CustomerOrderNumber, 
                   Extent2.CustomerOrderItemPosition, 
                   Extent2.CustomerOrderDate, 
                   Extent2.DeliveryDate, 
                   Extent2.CustomerReference, 
                   Extent2.IdOrderType, 
                   Extent2.NumberOrdered, 
                   Extent2.NumberAffirmed, 
                   Extent2.IdPositionType, 
                   Extent2.VoucherAmountInCent, 
                   Extent2.VoucherNumber, 
                   Extent2.SellingOrganizationName, 
                   Extent2.PurchaseOrderNumber, 
                   Extent2.PurchaseOrderItemPosition, 
                   Extent2.PurchaseOrderDate, 
                   Extent2.IdDistributionCenter, 
                   Extent2.IdMaterial, 
                   Extent2.Priority, 
                   Extent2.CreatedAt, 
                   Extent2.UpdatedAt, 
                   Extent2.UpdateOfDeliveryDateProcessed, 
                   Extent3.IdContactProfile, 
                   Extent3.Name, 
                   Extent3.EmailAddress, 
                   Extent3.LandlinePhone, 
                   Extent3.MobilePhone, 
                   Extent3.UseMail, 
                   Extent3.UseMobile, 
                   Extent3.IdPartner AS IDPARTNER1
            FROM backlogsap AS Extent2
            INNER JOIN contactprofile AS Extent3 
                    ON Extent2.IdPartner = Extent3.IdPartner) AS Join1
        ON Extent1.IdBacklogSAP = Join1.IdBacklogSap
 WHERE Extent1.IdBacklog = @p__linq__0
```

The problem is that the inner select works on a huge amount of data, which are joined together resulting in such a high computation that the database timeout is getting triggered and an error is returned. Only when that calculation has finished does the actual data reduction by that where clause happen.

I was kinda surprised by that statement and find it quite weird when all I needed was actually this:

```
SELECT Extent3.IdContactProfile, 
       Extent3.Name, 
       Extent3.EmailAddress, 
       Extent3.LandlinePhone, 
       Extent3.MobilePhone, 
       Extent3.UseMail, 
       Extent3.UseMobile, 
       Extent3.IdPartner
FROM backlog                                                AS Extent1
INNER JOIN backlogsap                                       AS Extent2
        ON Extent1.IdBacklogSAP = Extent2.IdBacklogSap
INNER JOIN contactprofile                                   AS Extent3
        ON Extent2.IdPartner = Extent3.IdPartner
WHERE Extent1.IdBacklog = @p__linq__0
```

This only takes 0.016 seconds to compute and fetch the data. Of course that duration might change getting more than one backlog entry by that where but compared to the other query it's negligible.

I'm currently bypassing that query by using the following:

```
dbContext.backlogs
    .Where(bl => bl.IdBacklog == idBacklog)
    .Join(this.DbContext.backlogsaps,
        bl => bl.IdBacklogSAP,
        blsap => blsap.IdBacklogSap,
        (bl, blsap) => new { Backlog = bl, BacklogSap = blsap })
    .Join(this.DbContext.contactprofiles,
        join => join.BacklogSap.IdPartner,
        cp => cp.IdPartner,
        (join, cp) => cp)
```

This results in the desired query and has finished quickly. However, I find the join methods little appealing and would prefer a statement like the initially intended one. Also I'd like to know why the SelectMany statement causes the nested select in the query and how one may be able to avoid it and actually get the short query.

Comment: Interesting. First, I presume this is EF6 with Sql Server? Then, one thing you could try is to come from the other side: `dbContext.contactprofiles.Where(cp => cp.partner.backlogssap.Any(bls => bls.backlogs.Any()))`.

Comment: One thing regarding "appeal" is that if you write `Join()`s and `SelectMany`s with the concise query syntax, they become a lot more readable: `from bl in dbContext.backlogs where bl.IdBacklog == idBacklog from cp in bl.backlogsap.partner.contactprofiles select cp`. It will make even more difference in your join example.

Comment: Also, I would have thought Sql Server could optimize the nested queries into what it would do on a join. Which version of Sql Server is this?